# Ask about the location shows Notification Panel on tablet model

Tags: android

As I know, From M Os, with tablet models have width larger than 600dp. Notification
Panel will be displayed at where we touch on

Example

1. When touch on at center of status bar (drag down Notification Panel at center of status bar) -> Notifcation Panel will be displayed at center of screen

[center of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXvkW.jpg)

2. When touch on at right of status bar (drag down Notification Panel at right of status bar) -> Notifcation Panel will be displayed at right of screen

[right of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OZxo.jpg)

3. When touch on at left of status bar (drag down Notification Panel at left of status bar) -> Notifcation Panel will be displayed at left of screen

[left of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPJCj.jpg)

I searched code at Statusbar.java, NotificationPanel.java, but cannot find out code that google handle it
Have anyone who know where google handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's under [NotificationPanelView#onTouchEvent()](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/NotificationPanelView.java#L876):

```
if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && isFullyCollapsed()) {
    MetricsLogger.count(mContext, COUNTER_PANEL_OPEN, 1);
    updateVerticalPanelPosition(event.getX()); //this is the function that carries out the logic
    handled = true;
}
```